# Debugger showing correct thumbnail preview, old posts not changed (Facebook)

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-debugger

So I have recently changed all my thumbnails to meet the requirements for larger thumbnails on Facebook, Pinterest and Twitter.

The sharing debugger for facebook shows the correct thumbnail preview when scraped and displays a large card, but if I go to my Facebook Wall the posts are still small cards with the old thumbnails? (I have also changed the filename of the images supplied for the cards, so not sure if this is a caching issue?)

Debugger Example:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.codesmite.com%2Farticle%2Fcreating-pure-css-modal-pop-ups

I ran all my previous shares through the Twitter Card Validator and they have updated all of my previous posts instantly to large summary cards.

Is it not possible for my old posts on Facebook to update, or is there a delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it not possible for my old posts on Facebook to update, or is there a delay?

Facebook doesn’t switch out thumbnail images in existing posts automatically. Would make it way too easy for the Bad Guys™ to make lots of users share a link with a nice kitten picture, and then later replace that thumbnail with grossest-thing-you-can-imagine …

Users have to manually update their post. In the single post view, there is an entry “refresh share attachment” in the dropdown menu.

Comment: Found it :) Thanks!